# Excel - Delete Cache

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have been extensively working on Power Queries and made changes in my queries which lead to the creation of too many pivot caches (14).

As I looked online to find a way to delete unused/empty cache, I stumbled upon this website https://contextures.com/xlpivot11.html#removedups

In there, Debra gives a macro to "List All Pivot Caches" from which I get the following output[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcXi5.png)

Debra also offers a macro to "Remove Duplicate Pivot Caches", which of course does not work in my situation (mine are unused, not duplicated). However, it means there might be a way to make it target the empty caches.

Does anyone have experience with that?

It is far more advanced than my current coding knowledge and I really need help.

Have a great weekend,

Luka

I could not try much, I do not know how to code to delete caches.

Comment: Power query doesn't create pivot caches. Creating a pivot table creates a pivot cache. Deleting the pivot table deletes the pivot cache. Your question says your pivot caches are unused, but your screenshot shows all of your pivot caches are being used by 1 pivot table each. Try deleting the pivot tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.